# Bicubic interpolation in C

Tags: c, image, interpolation, bicubic

im trying to deal with the **bicubic image interpolation in c**. Therefore i've built this small script.

*1. the "resize_image"-function:*

```
    void resize_image(PPMImage *source_image, PPMImage *destination_image, float scale) {

        uint8_t sample[3];
        int y, x;

        destination_image->x = (long)((float)(source_image->x)*scale);
        destination_image->y = (long)((float)(source_image->y)*scale);

        for (y = 0; y < destination_image->y; y++) {

            float v = (float)y / (float)(destination_image->y - 1);

            for (x = 0; x < destination_image->x; ++x) {

                float u = (float)x / (float)(destination_image->x - 1);
                sample_bicubic(source_image, u, v, sample);

                destination_image->data[x+((destination_image->y)*y)].red   = sample[0];
                destination_image->data[x+((destination_image->y)*y)].green = sample[1];  
                destination_image->data[x+((destination_image->y)*y)].blue  = sample[2];  
            }
        }
    }
```

*2. the "sample_bicubic"-function*

```
    void sample_bicubic(PPMImage *source_image, float u, float v, uint8_t sample[]) {

        float x = (u * source_image->x)-0.5;
        int xint = (int)x;
        float xfract = x-floor(x);

        float y = (v * source_image->y) - 0.5;
        int yint = (int)y;
        float yfract = y - floor(y);

        int i;

        uint8_t p00[3];
        uint8_t p10[3];
        uint8_t p20[3];
        uint8_t p30[3];

        uint8_t p01[3];
        uint8_t p11[3];
        uint8_t p21[3];
        uint8_t p31[3];

        uint8_t p02[3];
        uint8_t p12[3];
        uint8_t p22[3];
        uint8_t p32[3];

        uint8_t p03[3];
        uint8_t p13[3];
        uint8_t p23[3];
        uint8_t p33[3];

        // 1st row
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint - 1, yint - 1, p00);   
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 0, yint - 1, p10);
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 1, yint - 1, p20);
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 2, yint - 1, p30);

        // 2nd row
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint - 1, yint + 0, p01);
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 0, yint + 0, p11);
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 1, yint + 0, p21);
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 2, yint + 0, p31);

        // 3rd row
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint - 1, yint + 1, p02);
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 0, yint + 1, p12);
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 1, yint + 1, p22);
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 2, yint + 1, p32);

        // 4th row
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint - 1, yint + 2, p03);
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 0, yint + 2, p13);
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 1, yint + 2, p23);
        get_pixel_clamped(source_image, xint + 2, yint + 2, p33);

        // interpolate bi-cubically!
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            float col0 = cubic_hermite(p00[i], p10[i], p20[i], p30[i], xfract);
            float col1 = cubic_hermite(p01[i], p11[i], p21[i], p31[i], xfract);
            float col2 = cubic_hermite(p02[i], p12[i], p22[i], p32[i], xfract);
            float col3 = cubic_hermite(p03[i], p13[i], p23[i], p33[i], xfract);

            float value = cubic_hermite(col0, col1, col2, col3, yfract);

            CLAMP(value, 0.0f, 255.0f);

            sample[i] = (uint8_t)value;

            printf("sample[%d]=%d\n",i,sample[i]);      

        }
    }
```

*3. the "interpolation helpers"*

```
    float cubic_hermite(float A, float B, float C, float D, float t) {

        float a = -A / 2.0f + (3.0f*B) / 2.0f - (3.0f*C) / 2.0f + D / 2.0f;
        float b = A - (5.0f*B) / 2.0f + 2.0f*C - D / 2.0f;
        float c = -A / 2.0f + C / 2.0f;
        float d = B;

        return a*t*t*t + b*t*t + c*t + d;
    }

    void get_pixel_clamped(PPMImage *source_image, int x, int y, uint8_t temp[])  {

        CLAMP(x, 0, source_image->x - 1);
        CLAMP(y, 0, source_image->y - 1);

        temp[0] = source_image->data[x+(W*y)].red;
        temp[1] = source_image->data[x+(W*y)].green;
        temp[2] = source_image->data[x+(W*y)].blue;
    }
```

I've uploaded the complete code with all the stuff around [here](http://pastebin.com/sQDQg7SG).

**There are no syntax errors executing this code.**

But the output image confused me.

**The input Image (21x20Pixel):**

[image: INPUT IMAGE: 21x20Pixel]

**This input image is scaled up by 2 (42x40Pixel):**

[image: OUTPUT IMAGE: 42x40Pixel]

The interpolation seems to work fine at some points, but the image looks like pixels are shifted.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?
This script was made with the help of:
http://blog.demofox.org/2015/08/15/resizing-images-with-bicubic-interpolation/

**Thanks guys!**

(Please don't consider the efficiency of this code ... its aweful i know)

Comment: lol ... #include <windows.h>  // for bitmap headers.  Sorry non windows people!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your resize_image() function:

```
destination_image->data[x+((destination_image->y)*y)].red   = sample[0];
```

That should probably be

```
destination_image->data[x+((destination_image->x)*y)].red   = sample[0];
```

What helps debugging such cases is initializing your destination image with some "magic color" that's not present in your actual data (e.g. some awful pink:-)). Then you would probably notice that some destination pixels still have that color after the resize_image() call. This hints to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and I noticed that there is another problem.

From your init_destination_image() function:

```
img->data = (PPMPixel*)malloc(W * H * (int)scale * sizeof(PPMPixel));
```

Should be:

```
img->data = (PPMPixel*)malloc(W * H * (int)scale * (int)scale * sizeof(PPMPixel));
```

Such as both, the `W` and `H` are being scaled.